# How to select a form element based on the value from a field in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a dynamic form where I am starting with a drop-down field with two values: bar chart and trend chart. If bar chart is selected I want to show a multi-select drop-down box for the dimension values while if trend chart is selected I want to show a single-select drop-down box.

With the template and model shown below, the multi-select box is only shown after the module is saved the first time. How can I get the isBarChart variable to be set so I can use it to determine if the select box shown should be multi-select or single-select before the module has been saved.

Thanks.

From the template:

```
%div.select_module_type
  Module type:
  %select{ :class => "module_type" }
    {{#select module_type}}
    %option{ :value => '' }
    %option{ :value => 'bar_chart' } Bar chart
    %option{ :value => 'trend_chart' } Trend chart  
    {{/select}}


%div.select_dimension_value
  Dimension value:
  {{#if isBarChart}}
  %select.dimension_value{ 'multiple' => true }
    {{#select dimension_value}}
    {{/select}}
  {{else}}
  %select.dimension_value
    {{#select dimension_value}}
    {{/select}}
  {{/if}}
```

From the model:

```
  isBarChart: ->
    return @get('module_type') == 'bar_chart'
```

From the view:

```
  showDimensionValuesSelector: (e) ->
    $(@el).find('div.select_dimension_value').hide()
    $(@el).find('div.date').hide()

    this_selector = $(@el).find('select.module_type')

    table = $(@el).find('select.table').val()
    return true if table == ''

    dimension_selector = $(@el).find('select.dimension[data-table="'+table+'"]')
    dimension = dimension_selector.val()
    return true if dimension == ''

    $(@el).find('div.select_dimension_value .preloader').css('display', 'inline')
    $(@el).find('select.dimension_value').hide()
    $(@el).find('select.dimension_value').html('')
    $(@el).find('div.select_dimension_value').show()
    $(@el).find('div.date[data-table="'+table+'"]').show()

    self = @
    $.get(
      '/dashboards/'+@model.get('dashboard_id')+'/dashboard_modules/dimension_values', 
      { table: table, dimension: dimension },
      (data, status, xhr) ->
        _.each(data, (item) ->
          if item.value != null and self.model.has('dimension_value') and item.value.toString() == self.model.get('dimension_value').toString()
            selected = 'selected="selected" '
          else
            selected = ''

          $(self.el).find('select.dimension_value').append('<option '+selected+'value="'+item.value+'">'+item.name+'</option>')
        )

        $(self.el).find('select.dimension_value').prepend('<option value=""></option>')
        $(self.el).find('select.dimension_value').show()
        $(self.el).find('div.select_dimension_value .preloader').hide()
      ,
      'json'
    )
```

Answer (score 6):

since you have a model already, you can just set the value on the model without saving it to the server:

in your view:

```
events: {
  'change .module_type': handleModuleTypeChange
},

handleModuleTypeChange: function() {
  this.model.set({
    module_type: this.$el.find('.module_type').val()
  });
}
```

then listen to your model changes, rerender the template:

```
//view initialize
initialize: function () {
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
}
```

I'm not sure why the select has to be rendered after the model is saved...if that's the case, you may wanna move the Dimensions part into new views.

==============================================================

**EDIT: (Dec/01/2013)**

A simple jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8x7rU/

this is a simple example of DOM events changing the model, and then the model changes trigger view rendering.

in this case the whole view is rerendered  when the model attribute 'module_type' is changed. And, by changing the Module Type dropdown, the view is setting new 'module_type' values on the model.

lots of the DOM related logic is actually in the template, when the view rerenders, the template knows the current state of the model then render accordingly.

Comment: I added coffeescript versions of the changes and it refreshes but the dimension_value still doesn't change until after the module has been saved. I'll add the view as the values in the dimension_value are refreshed when the module_type is changed but the type of select box is not. I wonder if there is a way I can add this to the view?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you wanna achieve here. Can you post a jsfiddle? btw in my original answer i accidentally left a space between '.' and 'module_type' which is wrong :)

Comment: So I have a form. The top field in the form is module_type and it is ia drop down. There are two values; bar_chart and trend_chart. There is another field a couple steps down called dimension_value. If module_type == bar_chart then dimension_value should be a multi-select box. If module_type == trend_chart then dimension_value should be a single-select box.

Comment: I'll check into a jsfiddle. I'm not sure as this is all coffeescript and hamlbars.

Comment: I made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8x7rU/   see if that's somehting you are looking for. I'm not a coffee-script/handlebars expert, it's just pure backbone with default underscore template.

Comment: I gave you credit for the bounty although it does not work for me. The bounty request clearly states that this is for coffeescript. While your solution works in jsfiddle I cannot port it over to coffeescript in my backbone app successfully.

Comment: sry dude. i'm a coffee-script hater, but I don't think there would be any problem converting real javascript to coffeescript. :/